# git submodule update --remote --merge yields fatal: Needed a single revision

Tags: git, git-submodules, github-actions

Suppose I have a [repo](https://github.com/vvasuki/kAvyam) with the following submodule structure:

```
[submodule "themes/sanskrit-documentation-theme-hugo"]
    path = themes/sanskrit-documentation-theme-hugo
    url = https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/sanskrit-documentation-theme-hugo.git
    update = merge
[submodule "content"]
    path = content
    url = https://github.com/vvasuki/kAvyam.git
    branch = content
    update = merge
```

While checking out this repository in the cloud, I would like all the submodules to be updated to the latest commit from the respective remote branches.

In github actions, if I run (example [here](https://github.com/vvasuki/kAvyam/runs/2538762762?check_suite_focus=true) with [workflow file](https://github.com/vvasuki/kAvyam/actions/runs/825176589/workflow) ) `git submodule update --remote --merge` , I get this error `fatal: Needed a single revision` . What gives? Is there an alternative?

### Alternatives tried

`git submodule foreach "(git checkout $(git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$name.branch || echo master); git pull)&"` - this works on my computer, but not in github actions (master branch is [wrongly checked out](https://github.com/vvasuki/kAvyam/runs/2538751544?check_suite_focus=true) for submodule content).

Comment: You cannot merge with `--depth 1` (in general anyway; some very specific, relatively care cases may work). Use a deeper or full clone in the submodule.

Answer (score 1):

Trouble seems to have been with actions/checkout step. The following worked:

Disabling submodules initialization in the action as below

```
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@master
      with:
        submodules: false
```

Manual updation:

```
    - name: Update submodules
      if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request'}}
      run: |
        set -o xtrace
        git submodule update --init --recursive
        git submodule update --remote --merge --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning with a depth of `1` and then run the `git pull --recurse-submodules` command with `--depth 1`. I would suggest to replace most of that workflow with something along the lines of this that I personally use a lot as well too.

```yaml
name: Submodule Update

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
    tags:
    - '*'
  schedule:
  - cron: '20 * * * *'

jobs:
  submodule-update:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@main
      with:
        # we need the submodules.
        submodules: recursive

    - name: Update submodule.
      run: git submodule update --remote

    # this creates a commit with the worker's working tree changes (in this case from the submodule update command) and pushes it to a branch named "app/updated-submodules".
    - name: Create Pull Request
      id: cpr
      uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@main
      with:
        # you will need an Personal Access Token if you want workflow runs to trigger inside of the created pull request created by this workflow.
        token: ${{ secrets.GITSYNC_TOKEN }}
        commit-message: Update submodules.
        # do not change it does not change anything other than the github-actions account basically pushes it.
        committer: GitHub <noreply@github.com>
        author: any user here <any user's noreply github email here>
        signoff: true
        branch: app/updated-submodules
        base: main
        # delete branch after merge.
        delete-branch: true
        title: 'Update submodules.'
        body: |
          Update submodules
          - Auto-generated by [create-pull-request][1]

          [1]: https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request
        draft: false
```

Comment: https://github.com/vvasuki/kAvyam/runs/2618160522?check_suite_focus=true (with workflow file https://github.com/vvasuki/kAvyam/actions/runs/856121606/workflow ) show that the proposed solution does not work.

Comment: Alright I changed it to suggest you use something similar to what I normally use which usually works for me (however you do not need to use the ``create-pull-request`` action if what you want it to do is to commit the change and then push it you could then have a step that does that instead of using that action that I use for keeping the submodules up to date.

Comment: Only difference I noted: `submodules: recursive`, no `fetch-depth: 1` and `git submodule update --remote` did not work either - https://github.com/vvasuki/kAvyam/runs/2629793492?check_suite_focus=true (workflow file https://github.com/vvasuki/kAvyam/actions/runs/860321519/workflow )